# cut protection sleeves for power tools

Tags: safety

what is the best protective sleeve for working with power tools. My buddy's boss badly cut his forearm to the bone with a disc grinder cutting masonry and he wants to know if kevlar sleeves will be enough to maybe help in that it wouldn't cut as bad {to the bone and through tendons)?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. First, ouch. Second, product recommendations are unfortunately off-topic here.

Comment: Arm [chaps](https://m.stihlusa.com/products/protective-and-work-wear/chain-saw-protective-apparel/aprnchap/)? Good idea...

Comment: the chaps are meant to be used with a chainsaw. ... the interior of the chaps is filled with threads that foul up the chain and stop the chain movement. .... i am not sure that it would work with a fairly smooth grinder blade

Answer (score 4):

The guard that came with the grinder properly adjusted would be the best protection. The next is using the tool properly so the tool is pulling away from body parts not at them. Would a Kevlar shield or sleeve help to reduce damage to the body, Yes but only if the protective device is covering the area that the tool comes in contact with. I have seen a contractor get injured when using cutting disk and forcing it so when the blade broke it grabbed and took a big chunk of flesh if he would have had the guard on he probably would not have been injured.

Comment: +1 to training, conventional PPE (gloves, hearing, eye) and the user paying attention to what they're doing. Tools are as safe or unsafe as the user.